# How to use For loop inside XElement

Tags: c#, xelement, xdoc

I try to create an `XML document` from a recieved `List<T>` which `T` is the type of the list.

so, the problem is when I try to use a `for` loop inside `XElement` I get errors.

My idea is ccreating an `XML Document` contains elements based on the **`T`** `properties`

**So please how can I use the `for` loop inside the `XElement`?**

Comment: If you get an error, please paste it into your question. That makes it easier for us to see the problem. However, you cannot have a for-loop within a call to a method - that's invalid syntax. You need to call the `Add` method inside the loop instead.

Comment: thats the errors
https://imgur.com/MuiZ0pd

Answer (score 1):

As for your error, you cant pass a for-loop as a method parameter. I see what you're getting at here, but you're doing it kind of inverted. Instead of placing the for-loop into the add method, put the add method into the for loop:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < PropertiesLength; i++)
{ 
    var element = new XElement(dataAsList_Properties[i].Name, dataAsList_Properties[i].GetValue(d));
    xdoc.Root.Element(childElementsName).Add(element);
}
```

Also:

Might I suggest having T implement a certain interface? This will allow you setup methods that are available across all of your types so that your data is more accessible for your conversion to XML